Proving compactness is needed to assure the Lebesgue Number Lemma holds
I am attempting to prove compactness is needed to assure the Lebesgue Number Lemma holds via an actual example. My thought is using the interval $\left[0,1\right]$ then comparing that to $\left(0,1\right)$. My open cover for both intervals would be:
\begin{equation}
\mathcal{O} = \left\{\left(\frac{1}{n},1\right) : n \in \mathbb{N}\right\}
\end{equation}
This would hold for $\left[0,1\right]$, but not $\left(0,1\right)$. Is this an adequate example to show compactness is a needed assumption for the Lebesgue Number Lemma?

Adequate in showing that when we have a space (In this case $[0,1]$, and remove its compactness (thus becoming $(0,1)$), that the Lebesgue Number Lemma is no longer true. You are correct in that adequate would be where it exists in the compact case, but no the open interval.

$\mathcal O$ is not an open cover of $[0,1]$.

Hi @PaulFrost, after working down below with cheyne I think I see where my mindset was messed up. Thanks for pointing that out though as it makes sense why that is not an open cover.

I think you conflating counterexamples of removing the qualifier of a statement (i.e. compactness in this case) with proving a theorem. It doesn't sound like you are trying to "prove the Lebesgue Number Theorem" but you are trying to "prove compactness is needed". That is not going to happen with your examples and frankly it is not even guaranteed by the statement of the Lebesgue Number Lemma "If compact then Lebesgue Numbers exist"; as the statement is not an if and only if.
What you are considering is a perfectly adequate (counter-)example to the statement "Every cover $\mathcal{O}$ has a Lebesgue number". Take your cover $\mathcal{O} = \{U_n := (\frac{1}{n}, 1)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}_{>0}}$. Suppose that there existed a Lebesgue number $d > 0$. Then notice that the open set $U = (0, d)$ has diameter equal to $d$ but does not sit entirely inside any $U_n$; thus we have contradicted ``Every cover $\mathcal{O}$ has a Lebesgue number''.

Hi. That is a good point actually about it not being an iff statement. That pivots my thought process. Essentially, by proving a non-compact set does not have a Lebesgue number $d$ with an example cover, $\mathcal{O}$, then the theorem does not hold for non-compact space.

I also want to clarify one last things. The part "Notice that the open set $U = (0,d)$ has diameter equal to $d$". How come we can include $0$ as the infimum? Is it because $\frac{1}{n} : n \to \infty \implies 0$?

@melon regarding your second comment: Since $X = (0,1)$ is my space, I can consider any open subset; in particular I can choose $(0,d) \subset X$. The reason why I chose it related to what you said but the real reason is not that $\frac{1}{n} \to 0$ but that $\frac{1}{n} > 0$ for all $n$.
